# Which Ubuntu Boost Package includes the UUID library?

Tags: apt, c++, libraries, cmake, boost

I am building a C++ program using cmake on Ubuntu and which uses the Boost UUID library.  I could install the entire Boost suite using either

```
sudo apt install libboost-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt install libboost-all-dev
```

But, this seems like overkill and a waste of resources for what I need since Ubuntu has Boost packages which are more targeted.  That said, I haven't been able to find the one containing the UUID library.

So, what's the minimal package set I need to install to get the UUID library functionality?

Additional details ...

Version: 20.10 / Groovy

I have looked through [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com) but the packages list only the names of the libraries as far as I can see.  I don't see the list of C++ header files (i.e. uuid.hpp) included with each of the packages,

Comment: Which versions of Ubuntu? Which header file name? Have you tried to search on http://packages.ubuntu.com/ by yourself?

Comment: I'm on 20.10, and I started looking through packages.ubuntu.com, but there's not a lot of detail in the descriptions for the Boost packages I looked at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [search results](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=groovy&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=uuid.hpp) on packages.ubuntu.com you have to install the `libboost1.71-dev` package to get `uuid.hpp` header file.

---

When online search fails you can use local search by installing [`apt-file`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/apt-file):

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

to get something like

> ```
> $ apt-file search uuid.hpp
> libboost1.71-dev: /usr/include/boost/uuid/uuid.hpp
> libcaf-dev: /usr/include/caf/detail/get_root_uuid.hpp
> libqpid-proton-cpp12-dev: /usr/include/proton/uuid.hpp
> ```

Comment: Thanks... I didn't know about apt-file.  That should be handy in the future.

Comment: For that matter, I didn't see the file search feature on packages.ubuntu.com.  It was late when I posted that.  Thanks.